# how to modify the following code to find the specific word

Tags: regex

The text is:

> But these days, what most concerns me is not necessarily the other
>   motorists, but bicycle-motor vehicle crashes.

In the given text I have to tokenize the word Bicycle-motor under the expression " bicycle-motor vehicle crashes."

I have tried

```
but(.*)vehicle crashes
```

The word is tokenized but under the expression " but bicycle-motor vehicle crashes". I don't want "but" under the expression.

but(.*)vehicle crashes.

Comment: add tag for programming language as well

Comment: You use a capturing group so the value you are looking for is in capturing group 1. If you don't want the leading and trailing spaces and get the match before the first occurence of `vehicle crashes` you could use `\bbut\s+(.*?)\s+vehicle crashes\b` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/02whR8/1) If lookarounds are supported, you might also use `(?<=\bbut\s).*?(?=\s+vehicle crashes\b)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/02whR8/2)

Answer (score 2):

Use the *positive look behind (?< ...)* for `"but "` and the *positive look ahead (?= ...)* for `" vehicle crashes"`:

```
(?<=but )(.*)(?= vehicle crashes)
```

See it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cKc3O3/1).